# Run ansible task on multiple inventory host groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am looking to run the same task on multiple inventory groups, for eg:

```ini
[big_group]
greenhat
localhost
redhat
linux

[small_group]
localhost

[redhat_group]
redhat
```

From my playbook I need to run a task on both `small_group` and `redhat_group`

My task is as below

```yaml
  - name: Disable HTTPS service from firewalld
    firewalld:
      service: https
      permanent: false
      state: disabled
      zone: public
      immediate: true
    when: inventory_hostname in groups['small_group']
    when: inventory_hostname in groups['redhat_group']
```

Received a warning as

```
 [WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from firewall.yml, line 6, column 5, found a duplicate dict key (when). Using last defined value only.
```

Playbook result :

```
TASK [Disable HTTPS service from firewalld] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
skipping: [redhat]
```

How can I specify multiple groups in `when: inventory_hostname in groups[]`

Answer (score 9):

You cannot have several `when` clause in a task. In your case, you just have to join the two groups (`+`) and remove the multiple entries if any ( with the [`unique` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#unique), for future inventory changes).

```yaml
when: inventory_hostname in ((groups['small_group'] + groups['redhat_group']) | unique )
```

Meanwhile, there is a much more convenient way IMO using the [`inventory_hostnames` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/inventory_hostnames.html) and taking advantage of [patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) as you do in a normal play

```yaml
when: inventory_hostname in lookup('inventory_hostnames', 'small_group:redhat_group')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but I was able to get this working with the the two clauses in ( ) and an "or" condition

```
when: 
  - (inventory_hostname in groups["small_group"] or inventory_hostname in groups["redhat_group"] )
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically it is doable with a list:

```
when:
  - ansible_hostname in groups['small_group']
  - ansible_hostname in groups['redhat_group']
```

But the way with using lookup is more 'pro'.

Comment: This does not answer the question as the task will run only for hosts which belong to both groups.